# Drag views in android

Tags: java, android

I want to create a Draggable activity/fragment like the default settings screen in abdroid which opens when I pull down from HOme screen. By draggable i mean I want to pull the screen down from a point to close it.

I am trying to figure out the term used for this. I went through Drag views but that is used for moving view around the screen. Has someone solved this? Please help!

Comment: Did you mean to something like Drawer?

Comment: I am not sure if its a drawer.  From the drawers that I have seen, they occupy only half the screen. I will read throught the DrawerLayout documentation and let you know if that works for me. Thanks!!

Comment: I know for shure that In the AndroidSlidingUpPanel that I linked to you the drawer will take place just as you define the layout for the drawer so if it will be match_parent so it will take all the screen

Comment: Thnaks a lot!! It worked like charm. Another question I had is how do I move a relative layout vertically down (drag with finger), do you have any pointers to the documentation of that. I surfed for documentation didt find anything concrete. Thanks!!

Comment: better if you will write new question, show the relevant code you use and what exactly you want to acheive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good place to start is to look on

> [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html)

It for drag layout into the screen and out.

A pretty good library that handle the stuff for you is:

> [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

Answer (score 1):

Android does not provide any API to support development of the settings-like screen. If you have to implement it, you will have to do that by yourself.

In order to fake the settings-like pull down screen within your application, you will need to create similar UI layout and use it in combination with the swipe down gesture (which works only when you swipe from the top within your application) and `Animation`.